# How to use ejabberd for chat app passing server through API layer

Tags: android, api, xmpp, ejabberd, instant-messaging

**Present Setup** 
I am trying to build a WhatsApp like chatting app on Android.
In the backend hosted on cloud, I have setup an Ejabberd Server. 
Now using smack library on Android, I can connect and message other users via Ejabberd server I setup on my cloud.

**Context**
This works fine for now, but later I might want to move to MQTT based custom solution for chat replacing Ejabberd and that will force all my app users to compulsorily update their App, since app right now has in its source code stored URL of Ejabberd Server and directly communicates to it.

To solve this problem, I am trying to create a layer of API endpoints so that all communication happens from client phone to ejabberd server via API layer. So tomorrow if I replace Ejabberd server with custom MQTT solution (for scale), then I won't need my app users to update app, since API endpoints have same URL, and I can simply change code behind my API layer, thus keeping me free of depending on Ejabberd forever.

**TLDR : Problem I am facing**
I am not getting any resource on how to create API layer instead of letting client phones directly communicate with Ejabberd Server. Problem is as per XMPP protocol, client & Ejabberd server directly establish a persistant connection, so how do I put my API layer in between? Its been weeks of headbanging by now and I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really put your API Layer between this because XMPP is not publish/subscribe like pubsub.... and something HTTP API is also bad for chat because the client has to request everything and the server can't push anything. I would recommend you to stay with XMPP because it's made to scale very well.